# can I override ansible inventory from another yaml file with ips

Tags: ansible, yaml

task.yml

```
---
- hosts: servers
  tasks
  ...
  ...
```

inventory.yml

```
[servers]
"{{server-1}}" ansible_ssh_user="{{server1_user}}" ansible_ssh_private_key="{{ssh_key}}"
```

variables.yml

```
server-1: localhost
server1_user: user
ssh_key: /home/user/ssh.pem
```

command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml \
tasks.yml \
 --extra-vars @variables.yml
```

Every variable except `server-1` is overridden. Is there any way I can do it?
I know there is a concept called dynamic inventories. Is it possible to **pass the ips from a YAML** file?

Comment: I wonder why the inventory is called `.yml`. It usually looks more like an ini file, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't.

<sup>(and even fixing the syntax error ― hyphen in a variable name ― won't change it)</sup>

Inventory hostname (`inventory_hostname`) is an alias to be used in plays, it is not supposed to be dynamic.

The actual hostname used for connection can be defined in [`ansible_host` variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups), so what you can do is:

```
[servers]
server-1 ansible_host="{{server1}}" ansible_ssh_user="{{server1_user}}" ansible_ssh_private_key="{{ssh_key}}"
```

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find all the options I can give in an inventory file?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters